# Can CreateFile function open a handle to the devices that are only listed under Global?? directory in WinObj utility?

Tags: c++, winapi, device

You know - in C++, you can obtain a handle to an I/O device by passing its path as the first parameter in a call to CreateFile function. But I wonder how CreateFile locates and identifies the device by the path given. One day, I discovered something about this topic using WinObj utility, which may be probably true.
In WinObj, there is a directory named *Global??* which is located under the root directory, and can be seen on the left pane. This directory contains lots of items of type "SymbolicLink".
When you pass the path of an I/O device (such as "\.\C:" or "\.\Changer0") as the first parameter in a call to `CreateFile` function, the CreateFile function parses out the path and removes "\.\" from it to find a portion of the path. Then it searches the *Global??* directory for a SymbolicLink with the same name as that portion. Then it finds the address that the symbolic link refers to, which is the primary **Physical Device Object Name** (for example, "\Device\CdRom0").
So, is my discovery true? Are the devices contained within *Global??* directory the only devices that `CreateFile` function can open? Just to mention something:  not all of the items in *Global??* directory refer to a device, I guess.

#### The second part of my question

One day, I wanted to decrease the screen brightness of my monitor programmatically, by sending an `IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS` control code to my monitor. The problem was that I didn't know what to specify for the first parameter of `CreateFile` function. So I did the following:

1. I opened *Device Manager* and found my monitor device among the list. The name of that device was "Generic Non-PnP Monitor".
2. I right clicked on that list item and clicked on *Properties*.
3. In the *Properties* window, I clicked on *Details* tab. Then I selected *Physical Device Object name* from the *Property* drop-down list.
4. On the value section, I found the text "\Device\0000006f".
5. In WinObj, I searched the *Global??* directory for a SymbolicLink which refers to "\Device\0000006f". The name of that SymbolicLink was long:

> DISPLAY#Default_Monitor#5&1193a8c7&0&UID100663553#{866519b5-3f07-4c97-b7df-24c5d8a8ccb8}

6. Then I put a "\.\" before the aforementioned SymbolicLink name and
   specified it as the first parameter of `CreateFile` function.

Any ideas on how to do all of this operation programmatically? I mean, I'd like my program itself to obtain the value of `lpFileName` parameter. Not I place this string directly in my program's source code.

Comment: you can use "\\\\?\\globalroot\\Device\\0000006f"` - so you can use any device name in call `CreateFile`

Comment: @RbMm Thank you. It works. But imagine you have the display name of a device as it appears in Device Manager. Then how would you obtain its Physical Device Object name as it appears in WinObj?

Comment: you need call `CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW` with `GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR` and use returned name in call `CreateFile`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

at first in `CreateFile` we can use any name from NT namespace, if prefix it with **`\\?\globalroot`** or even better **`\\?\global\globalroot`** prefix. say if we want open `\Device\0000006f` we can use `\\?\globalroot\Device\0000006f` or `\\?\global\globalroot\Device\0000006f` name. the win32 sybsystem when convert win32 path to NT-path - if view '\?` prefix - simply convert it to `\??\`. so nt path will be look like `\??\[global\]globalroot\Device\0000006f`. the `\??` is [virtual directory](https://googleprojectzero.blogspot.com/2015/10/windows-drivers-are-truely-tricky.html) - it not exist really. object manager look in [Local and Global MS-DOS Device Names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/local-and-global-ms-dos-device-names) when view `\??\`. first in local (which look like `\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<luid>`) and if not found in global - `\GLOBAL??`. however in any local dos device directory exist symbolic link `Global` which point to `\Global??`. as result after parse `\??\global` we will be redirected to `\Global??`. then in `\Global??` folder exist symbolic link `GLOBALROOT` which is empty - point to root of NT namespace.
as result after parse
`\\?\global\globalroot\Device\0000006f` will be re-parsed to `\Device\0000006f` and  `\\?\globalroot\Device\0000006f` also, if no `globalroot` object in Local device namespace (usually not exist, but suddenly somebody create it).

now about how open monitor device. we must not hard-code any device name. instead we need search for devices which support [`GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/guid-devinterface-monitor) by call [`CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538463(v=vs.85).aspx) and use returned name in call `CreateFile`

```
#include <ntddvdeo.h>

CONFIGRET EnumMonitors()
{
    CONFIGRET err;

    static volatile UCHAR guz;

    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);
    ULONG BufferLen = 0, NeedLen = 128;

    union {
        PVOID buf;
        PWSTR pszDeviceInterface;
    };

    for(;;) 
    {
        if (BufferLen < NeedLen)
        {
            BufferLen = RtlPointerToOffset(buf = alloca((NeedLen - BufferLen) * sizeof(WCHAR)), stack) / sizeof(WCHAR);
        }

        switch (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_ListW(const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR), 
            0, pszDeviceInterface, BufferLen, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
        {
        case CR_BUFFER_SMALL:
            if (err = CM_Get_Device_Interface_List_SizeW(&NeedLen, const_cast<PGUID>(&GUID_DEVINTERFACE_MONITOR), 
                0, CM_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_LIST_PRESENT))
            {
        default:
            return err;
            }
            continue;

        case CR_SUCCESS:

            while (*pszDeviceInterface)
            {
                HANDLE hFile = CreateFileW(pszDeviceInterface, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 0,
                    OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                if (hFile != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    OVERLAPPED ov = {};
                    DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS db;
                    DeviceIoControl(hFile, IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS, 0, 0,
                        &db, sizeof(db), 0, &ov);
                    CloseHandle(hFile);

                    DbgPrint("(%x,%x,%x) %S\n", db.ucDisplayPolicy, db.ucACBrightness, db.ucDCBrightness, pszDeviceInterface);
                }

                pszDeviceInterface += 1 + wcslen(pszDeviceInterface);
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Talking about parsing "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\<luid>" and following the "Global" link to "\Global??" is a useful way to understand the big picture of how device lookup works, but of course in practice it isn't implemented like this. Initially, from the token's `LogonSession`, we have the session's `pDeviceMap`, which references the `DosDevicesDirectory`. Subsequently the `DeviceMap` gets cached in the Process object, and used unless a thread is impersonating. The Directory object itself also caches the `DeviceMap`, from which the `GlobalDosDevicesDirectory` is accessed as a 'shadow' directory.

Comment: Unless we're in a SYSTEM process, which is hard coded to use the system device map, in which "\Global??" is the `DosDevicesDirectory` and `GlobalDosDevicesDirectory` is `NULL`, to terminate further lookup. Nowadays we also have server silos to contend with, with container namespaces. So this is handled more flexibly, and the default global silo device map is set as `PspHostSiloGlobals->ObSiloState.SystemDeviceMap`.

Comment: Your answer is good. Though it raised a question for me. Under "\Sessions\0\DosDevices\" folder, there are three subfolders with weird names (you called their names "luid"). What does each of them represent? Also, in each of these folders, there's an item named Global which you explained well about it. But in one of these folders, there are two additional items "NDISTAPI" and "NDPROXY". What are those two items?

Comment: @JavadBayat - this numbers - is logon session id (luid) from token.run this [utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/logonsessions) for example and compare luids in winobj and from it. of course in some sessions can be created local objects. otherwise which sense in folder if it will be always empty ?

Comment: Note that local logon-session devices take precedence over global devices. As I explained in my first comment, the Object Manager doesn't use the "Global" link, so here we see the real reason that this link exists. With it, you can still refer to a "\\?\Global\Z:" when local "Z:" exists. That's also why RbMm said that "\\?\Global\GlobalRoot" is better than "\\?\GlobalRoot" ; given the chance that another program set a local "GlobalRoot" link via `NtCreateSymbolicLinkObject`.

Comment: Also note that there's no Directory for the SYSTEM logon session (0x3e7) in "\Sessions\0\DosDevices". As I explained in my second comment, the SYSTEM logon uses the system device map (or current silo device map), which uses the system's global DOS device directory as the primary `DosDevicesDirectory`. For consistency in this case, the global DOS devices directory has a "Global" link (e.g. "\Global??\Global", if not a silo) that points back to its parent, even though this seems a bit silly.